# Symfony and bootstrap layout ignored when updated to 4.1.0

Tags: symfony, bootstrap-4, upgrade, symfony-forms

I use Symfony 4 and Bootstrap 4 with this layout: `bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig`.

When I update Symfony from 4.0 to 4.1.0, part of the layout is ignored. How can I fix that?
Before i had my Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType with the good translation with the locale language and compact field, after i have english and large field.
See picture of [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVIaY.png) and [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnCcm.png)

Comment: This file is still used, are you trying to override this file ? Can you show us your file ? And the path of your file ?

Answer (score 1):

You should read [this blog post](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-improved-bootstrap-4-form-theme). Since the update a couple of things have changed. You say the layout is ignored, but what exactly does that mean? Also see the [current documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/bootstrap4.html) of the form theme.